# Query specific mongo secondary using c# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongo (2.0.3) replica set.

If I connect to a specific node (i.e. my connection string does not include more than one host) using the standard c# driver, and specify slaveOk(), will that query be satisfied by a random member of the set, or only ever by the node I connected to?

If the former, how can I achieve the latter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your connection string only has one host name (and does not have either replicaSet=name or connect=replicaSet) the C# driver will connect in direct mode to that one server and use only it.

Replica set semantics (where it uses the whole set) is triggered either by listing more than one host name (called the seed list), or by using replicaSet=name or connect=replicaSet.

So if you want to use just that one host you are on the right track. You will have to specify slaveOk on the connection string or the connect will fail if that server is not the primary.

Comment: Thanks Robert. The MongoServerSettings class has a property called ConnectionMode, which can be set to direct or replica set. Do you perhaps know what impact this has in the context of what you've specified above?

Comment: If you set the connection mode to replicaset then the driver will connect using replica set semantics even if the connection string only has a single server. Normally the connection mode is defaulted (the default is direct for connection strings with a single server and replicaset for connection strings with multiple servers).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with MongoDb driver 2.0 and MongoDb server 3.0. Also, according to the documentation there is no slaveOk parameter and readPreference doesn't seem to help here either.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.WithReadPreference(ReadPreference.Secondary)` for the collection provider

Answer (score 1):

specifying *connect=direct* as a parameter in the connection string solved my issue of connecting to secondaries via Powershell.

Comment: +1. It seems it is undocumented, but it works perfectly with the 2.x c# driver (contrary to the accepted solution which is 1.x only)